# Documents repeating in the query of elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm new to elasticsearch. I need to build the query dynamically, where for each field name the the corresponding file is fetched

**I have the below query, can anyone say if its the right approach? Also with this query, the documents are just repeating for one particular file name**

Please let me know how to go about it

```
GET index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "field_name": "program"
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "field_value": "aaa-123"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "field_name": "species"
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "field_value": "mouse"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "field_name": "model name"
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "field_value": "b45"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },"aggs": {
    "2": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "myfile_file_name.keyword",
        "size": 1000,
        "order": {
          "_key": "asc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "3": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "field_name.keyword",
            "size": 1000,
            "order": {
              "_key": "asc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

mapping and Output

```
{
       "_index" : "test",
       "_type" : "test_data",
       "_id" : "123",
       "_score" : 1.0,
       "_source" : {
         "document_id" : 123,
         "m_id" : 1,
         "source" : "ADDD",
         "type" : "M",
         "name" : "Animal",
         "value" : "None",
         "test_type" : "Test123",
         "file_name" : "AA.zip",
         "description" : "testing",
         "program" : ["hello"],
         "species" : ["mouse"],
         "study" : ["Study1"],
         "create_date" : "2020-08-20 11:51:21.152",
         "update_date" : "2020-08-20 11:51:21.152",
         "source_name" : "Anim",
         "auth" : ["na"],
         "treatment" : ["TR001", "TR002", "TR004"],
         "timepoint" : ["72", "48"],
         "findings_reports" : "na",
         "model" : ["None",],
         "additional" : "{'view': '', 'load': []}",
         "data" : "Pre"
       }
     },
   ]
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your mapping, your sample docs and expected Output ?

Comment: i have added, please check and let me know

Comment: you just added a sample doc, not mapping. Also I need more sample docs and your expected output, you should make your question very clear in order to get the community help.